# ADB Method freezes with python adb.devices()

Tags: python, adb, freeze

I have installed adb through android studio and connected bluestack properly, and if I run with cmd:

> adb shell input touchscreen swipe x x x x y

its working fine .

Now this is my code to connect to bluestack with my python app:

```
from ppadb.client import Client

adb = Client(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555)
devices = adb.devices()

print(devices)


if len(devices) == 0:
    print('no devices')
    quit()

device = devices[0]
```

Whenever I get to devices = adb.devices(), the app instantly freezes. By freeze I mean that the app isn't returning anything (even if I use print) and I cannot kill it with ctrl+c.
[vscode freezed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOtZr.png)

How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

- I also faced the same and then from this ticket
  https://github.com/Swind/pure-python-adb/issues/50
  I found ppadb
  looks for 5037 port.
- So I used subprocess to forward my memu port 21503 to 5037

Note: to run adb command in subprocess you need to **add adb path to your environment vairables path**

```
import ppadb
import subprocess
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient

print("connecting to adb")
command = 'adb forward 127.0.0.1:21503 127.0.0.1:5037'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print('standard output: %s \n error output: %s \n',(stdout,stderr)) 
adb = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
devices = adb.devices()
for device in devices:
    print (device.serial)
if len(devices) == 0:
    print('no device attached')
    quit()
else:
    print('found %d devices' % len(devices))
device = devices[0]
device.shell("input touchscreen swipe 300 300 1000 2000")
```